# Unusual uses of 'presume'

Tags: meaning

What are the meanings of

> to presume against

or

> to presume for

that I found e.g. in [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bail_Act_2013) and in [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=presume_INF+for%2C+presume_INF+against&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cpresume_INF%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpresume%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresumed%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresuming%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresumes%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cpresume_INF%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpresumed%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresumes%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresuming%20against%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: You know you can click on the links below the graph to see the usages.

Comment: @Jim Seeing the usages doesn't help much in understanding what it means in that context.

Comment: @Barmar - It was pretty clear to me after I read through several of them.  (I didn’t look at the Wikipedia aeticle.)

Comment: @Jim Well sorry, even researching Merriam-Webster does not provide any meaning, so I thought this site to be the right, non-beginner place to ask. But obviously, I was very much mistaken. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary definition at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/presume) is

> to take for granted, assume, or suppose

In the Wikipedia article you link to, "to presume against bail" apparently means that the default would be to not grant bail to criminal defendants. So more generally, "presume against X" means to assume X does not happen. By contrast, "presume for X" means to assume X does happen.

Comment: Your answer provides more information than even Merriam-Webster. Very much obliged.